# "Bakeshop" vs. "bake shop" vs. "bakery" vs. "bakery shop" vs. "bakehouse" for a baker's shop, and "bakeries" for "baked goods" in AmE

Tags: american-english, word-usage

Are all four terms in current use in AmE today to refer to a bakery's shop where bread and other baked stuff like cakes and pastries are sold?

As far as I know, "bakeshop", "bakehouse", and "bakery" can designate also the workplace where the baked goods are made. But "bakery", unlike "bakeshop" and "bakehouse", can additionally
refer to an industrial baking facility, i.e. a baking plant.

Also, can the baked goods [bread, cakes and pastries produced in a bakery] be referred to as "bakery" or "bakeries" in AmE?

Even though the latter is validated by the OED for BrE [source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bakery), I can't seem to find a US dictionary online that states it as fact for AmE.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bakery

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bakery

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bakery

Comment: How is a *bakehouse* different from the workplace where the baked goods are made? I thought that was its definition.

Comment: You know, NG, You really should visit the US after all this exploration of the language. I'd be happy to take you to the best bakeries I know of in Philly and NYC. :)

Comment: @medica You bet I will someday! Thanks for offering to take me on a bakery spree with you in the New England/Mid Atlantic areas where you live, I'm taking the invite without hesitation.:-)

Comment: @PeterShor Good point for "bakehouse".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, in AmE, a bakery is a place where baked goods are made, and usually also sold (though there are some factory bakeries which don't sell retail.)

I have some fond memories of the local bakeries as I was growing up. Somehow, they seem to have been replaced, but not by *bakeshops*. I never saw that word until this post. (Similarly, I have never seen *bakery store*.)

Now it seems quality baked goods are sold in a variety of settings: the bakery section of a grocery store, patisseries, cafés, specialty pastry shops/stores, and sandwich restaurants such as Panera Breads (which bills itself as a "bakery-café fast casual restaurant".) Cakes are often in specialty shops which only do cakes & cupcakes, as well as in the bakery section of stores.

If people use the term "bakehouse", it must be an outmoded or industry term; I have never heard it.

The baked goods are not referred to as "bakery" or "bakeries". Those are the places that make and sell baked goods. Though shops are where people ply their trade (butcher shops, barber/beauty shops, etc., a baker works in a bakery, though I can see how some people might call it a baker's shop. But not hereabouts.

This is from the New England/Mid-Atlantic areas of the US.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard *bakery store* or *bakeshop* used in the US. Google NGrams (of written english) report similarly. When we buy baked goods, we go to the bakery or to that part of the grocery referred to as the bakery (or, in store-clerk speak, just *bakery*, as in "You want fresh pies? They're over in bakery.")

First, just showing *Bakery*, US vs GB, they have similar levels of use in both the US and British corpus:
[image]

Comparing Bakery, bakery store, bakeshop, bake shop  (US only), it shows very little or no usage of bakery store or bakeshop:
[image]

Comparing Bakery, bakery store, bakeshop, bake shop  (GB only), it also shows very little or no usage of bakery store or bakeshop:
[image]

While I haven't heard *bakeshop* very often, *cake shop* or *pastry shop* are more common, but still far below *bakery* in the US literature:
[image]

As for your second question, I have never heard what we call *baked goods* or *pastries* (a subset of baked goods) referred to simply as *bakery* the way your british dictionary does. Searching several dictionaries with [Onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Bakery&ls=a), only [this one](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bakery) (yourdictionary.com) and [this one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bakery) (Oxford Dictionaries) refer to *bakery* as including baked goods. There were about twenty dictionaries that made no mention of this definition.

Comment: Good point (your second point) about the proximity of bakery as an adjective. I'll retry with bakery as a noun. -- I don't understand your first point. If I said or implied bakery is only where baked goods are sold, that would be wrong, but I don't see it in my answer. -- And cakes and pastries are a special type of baking, which is why I mentioned them as a subset of bakeries; they are not where one buys bread, for example.

Comment: There are a few glitches in your ngrams, Jim. First, "bakery" -- like "bake shop" to a lesser degree -- can sure enough refer to the place where the baked goods are produced. But, also to the place where these are sold. Plus, the bakehouse and the store sometimes are on different premises. Secondly, "bakery" can be used as a modifier for loads of things like bakery goods, bakery supplier, etc.. And so, while I pretty much agree on the overall analysis, I must say there's some kinda flaw in your results. Also, to my perspective, a cake or pastry shop are not strictly speaking a bakery.

Comment: Even if you try with "bakery" as a noun, there still will be a flaw to your results, as long as "bakery" as a noun can refer to an industrial facility like a factory where baked goods are produced, but not sold. And so, ngrams are not relevant in such case.

Comment: Then at this point, I'll just have to tell you that, flawed as the results may appear, they are consistent with my living with American English for nearly 60 years. :) *Bakery* is, by far, the most common expression for a a place where baked goods are made or sold, and the other expressions (bake shop, bakeshop, and bakehouse) are for the most part unused here. By the way, the NGRAMS changed very little, which is what I would have expected.

Comment: Jim A bakery implies the making of bread and other baked goods, but only a certain type of them known in France as viennoiserie. This includes croissants, brioches, chocolatines, pains aux raisins, and the like. A cake shop or a pastry shop is more like what we call in France a patisserie. Pastry shops generally offer a wide variety of cakes including viennoiseries, but also pastries like napoleons and other fine delicacies. However, pastry shops don't make or sell bread. And so, a cake shop or pastry shop can't be referred to as a bakery.

Comment: So, now I'm curious, how long have you lived in the US?

Comment: Did I ever say the contrary? :-)

Comment: When did I say I ever lived in the US?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how you could be more familiar with AmE than I am, yet we have such differing views on something that is AmE.

Comment: I'm just sort of a dictionary worm. ;-)

Comment: Well, here you have a chance to talk to "the real deal", so take advantage of it while your here. You have great questions, as far as I'm concerned. (I'm puzzled by you comments here, but that's not going to change my opinion.) Comme j'ai dit, je suis un fan. Bon courage. @+

Comment: Check this out, Jim. "Today Mom and I went to get some bakeries" http://mcferrinfamilyblog.blogspot.fr/2010/02/mexico-city-distric-federal.html

Comment: Merci, Jim. Je vais essayer de dormir un peu a présent. Bonne continuation et a très bientôt sur ELU! @+

Comment: just realized I erred by putting the wrong term. I most certainly wrote bakery store by analogy with grocery store. Anyways, it's all fixed now. You can change your ngrams if you want to. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I happen to live in Wisconsin.  While I have seen it written, I have never personally heard an actual person use the term "baked goods".  The goods in question are invariably referred to as "bakery" here.  A common roadside sign advertises "Fresh Bakery".  I have assumed this to be referring not to the establishment itself, but rather the products on sale within. We are however noted for the "howlers" of our local dialects, most of which are heavily influenced by the German or related languages spoken here until the last war.  My hometown of Milwaukee is renowned for the phrase, "down by Schuster's where the streetcar turns the corner around".  So while "bakery" for "baked goods" may not be in received grammar, it is at least locally in common usage.